# Handle global and HTTP exception with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to handle global(StatusCode 500) and http exception in Asp.Net MVC Using Custom Error Page with Proper HTTP status code using Application_Error() event in Global.asax file. To make it simple actually I have only the same view error for all types of handled exception.

Now the problem is when a 500 exception is handled it goes a first time in the else section of the Application_Error and then it goes back to the if section and finally return 404 http exception instead of 500 exception.

How I can fix that by stop running after it goes in the else section of Application_Error when a 500 exception is handled ?

This is my configuration :
web.config

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>

 <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="400"/>
        <remove statusCode="401"/>
        <remove statusCode="403"/>
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <remove statusCode="500"/>
        <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error"/>
        <error statusCode="401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error"/>
        <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error"/>
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error"/>
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error"/>
      </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Method Application_Error():

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

        // Clear the response stream
        HttpContext httpContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        httpContext.Response.Clear();
        httpContext.ClearError();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);


        if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException)) //It's an Http Exception
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());

            switch (routeData.Values["statusCode"])
            {
                case 400:
                    routeData.Values.Add("status", "400 - Bad Request");
                    break;
                case 401:
                    routeData.Values.Add("status", "401 - Access Denied");
                    break;
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values.Add("status", "403 - Forbidden");
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values.Add("status", "404 - Page Not Found");
                    break;
                case 500:
                default:
                    routeData.Values.Add("status", "500 - Internal Server Error");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
            routeData.Values.Add("status", "500 - Internal Server Error");

        }

        // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
        httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
        IController controller = new ErrorController();
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
        Response.End();
        // clear error on server
        //Server.ClearError();
    }
```

Controller ErrorController :

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Error/
        public ActionResult Error(int statusCode, string status, Exception exception)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
            ViewBag.Status = status;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this is that the type of `Exception` thrown by the application will not always be `HttpException`. It could be `SQLException, SystemException, IndexOutOfRangeException` etc. And the status codes are always associated with `HttpExceptions` only. That's why your code first goes in `else` part & then into `if` part.

Though it should not come again on `if` part but if it is coming, then you must check that the page you are redirecting user is not further throwing any other exception.

I would also recommend removing the last parameter from your code because Exception is a complex type & we normally do not pass complex types in Get requests.

Convert this

```
public ActionResult Error(int statusCode, string status, Exception exception)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Error(int statusCode, string status)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply